# Vsphere web not showing changes made by ssh console

Tags: debugging, networking, service, vmware, vsphere

I've connected to my Vsphere host through ssh console and added a port group on a virtual switch and also assigned it a VLAN id. When I go to the web interface, what I've created is not displayed there despite it showing when I run "esxcfg-vswitch -l".

My problem is that if I try to create it through the web GUI or wizard, I receive an error saying that it already exists. Can anyone provide some insight on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,  I found out you need to restart the management services for them to be pushed.

Restart Management agents in ESXi Using ESXi Shell or Secure Shell (SSH):
    1. Log in to ESXi Shell or SSH as root.

For Enabling ESXi Shell or SSH, see Using ESXi Shell in ESXi 5.x and 6.x (2004746).
    2. Restart the ESXi host daemon and vCenter Agent services using these commands:

/etc/init.d/hostd restart

/etc/init.d/vpxa restart

From https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003490